# Streaming a video file from firebase storage using Javascript

Tags: javascript, firebase, video, firebase-storage

I have worked with images, they seem to do well when you use the downloadURL() to embed them in html tags,but the video doesn't work.
I tried using the video and iframe tag in html but it doesn't work. From what I understand, is that incoming file is not a video but a general file, it downloads with ".mp4 extension. Please suggest what should I do. I am working on a small time project where users can upload videos and watch other user's video.

Answer (score 0):

Use downloaded Url to play video in chat.
In this code, i have passed a video URI to which I want to get the downloadable URL and then set the source of the video element.

Note:- Remember to put the controls property to video tag.

```
this.storage.refFromURL(videoUri).getMetadata().then(function(metadata) {
      console.log('metadata',metadata.downloadURLs[0]);
      vidElement.src = metadata.downloadURLs[0];
    });
```

Comment: As of writing this, `downloadURLs` doesn't exist in metadata (anymore).